# Bootstrap not working without Visual Studio Code live-server plugin

Tags: html, css, ide, visual-studio-code, bootstrap-4

I am using visual code IDE for coding and a plugin "live server" which is very handy for quick checks of the changes made in code and everything with bootstrap worked excellently.

But when I tried to open a .html file just by double-clicking on it (**without live server from Visual Code IDE**), it opened like there was totally no css or bootstrap's js.

Looking forward for any help.

A really small snippet of code with necessary parts here:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Main css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
  <body>

    <header>
      <!-- Fixed navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md fixed-top bg-light border-bottom">
        <a class="navbar-brand text-info" href="#">AirFly</a> 

        <!-- Hamburger menu -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div style="position:relative;" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <div class="float-right">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link text-uppercase text-info" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-uppercase text-dark" href="about.html">About us</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-uppercase text-dark" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
              </li> 
            </ul>
          </div>
          </div>    
      </nav>
    </header>

<script src="/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/weather.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the browser's [DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) to further investigate why the asset files (CSS and JS) are not loaded correctly?

Comment: I just checked it... Such a stupid mistake :D
"Failed to load resource:  net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND "

But no idea why, I didn't touch the file address.

Comment: try prefixing ./ (dot slash) to all your paths

Comment: Sir, I love you. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this attribute from links,

---

```
integrity="sha384AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p"
crossorigin="anonymous"
```

then your page design will be working perfectly.